# mysql how to combine two select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database with records of date-time and a measurement value.

I've been writing two separate queries, one to return the total count of all daily records between certain times of day for the previous month, and the same query but a count of only when the measurement value is below threshold.
  I then manually divide the theshold count by total count for each day, and I am able to get a % uptime or SLA.

So I have two questions:
1) Can I combine these two queries into one query.  **I found the Answer to #1, see below**
2) Can I go ahead and do the math in the queries, so what I get returned is just a listing of each day, the count above, the count below, and the % above or below threshold...

Sample data and query are listed below.
TableA
hostname, date_time, value

#### Sample Query to return days from previous month, excluding weekend days.

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  DATE(date_time),
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN rssi_val < 100
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  )
FROM TableA
WHERE hostname = 'hostA'
  AND DATE(date_time) BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'
  AND TIME(date_time) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
  AND DAYOFWEEK(date_time) NOT IN (1, 7)
GROUP BY DATE(date_time);
```

So now I just want to know how to add a 4th column that gives the percent uptime/downtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
select count(*), 
       DATE(date_time), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rssi_val<100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rssi_val<100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/count(*) as percentage
from TableA 
where hostname='hostA' 
and DATE(date_time) between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-31' 
and TIME(date_time) between '06:00:00' and '18:00:00' 
and DAYOFWEEK(date_time) NOT IN (1,7) 
group by DATE(date_time);
```

Comment: No I tried select count(*), DATE(date_time),   
           SUM(CASE WHEN rssi_val<100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as THRESH, 
           (THRESH / count(*)) as SLA
    from TableA ...etc

Comment: You can't use the alias in the `SELECT` itself, it's why you have to repeat the `SUM(CASE...` ... but +1 on the comment cause at least, you tried something :)

Comment: Thanks Fabien, that worked.  One more, is there a way to say 1 - so instead of .0244 i get back .9997 or .9998

Comment: And I tried to format my comment using the mini-markdown, but was unable to create any linebreaks.

Comment: Yes, you can do `1 - (SUM(CASE WHEN rssi_val<100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/count(*))`

Comment: Yep, thanks, I just tried that as well as add * 100 to get a real percentage value.  Thanks much!

Comment: So if you can flag my answer, it will be appreciate :)

Comment: I tried to but I don't have enough reputation points.  IS there another way for me to do that?

Comment: OK, i chose the answer, I just couldn't up vote it.  Thanks again